# Yahoo Media Player - excluding videos?

Tags: javascript, media-player

I am using the yahoo media player on my site to play audio files.

http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/

On the same page I have a video player, and when someone clicks on a video to play, it plays it in the yahoo player and not in the video player on the page.  Does anyone know how I can exclude videos from playing in the yahoo media player... I looked in the documentation and couldn't find anything on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Yahoo Media Player doesn't have an "exclude" function, but it has an "include" function. If any of your media files have *class="htrack"* then only those files will be opened with the player. All other supported files should be ignored.

Example:

<a href="file1.mp3" class="htrack">Play Song 1</a><br>

<a href="file1.mp3">Download Song 1</a><br>

<a href="file2.mp3" class="htrack">Play Song 2</a><br>

<a href="file2.mp3">Download Song 2</a><br>

<a href="file.flv" rel="shadowbox">Watch this FLV</a>

In this example, only the first and third link will play through the YMP.